# Is there a way to make a Windows Server consume it's own shared printers?

Tags: printing, network-printer, windows-server-2019

I have Windows Server 2019 with some network printers installed using Standard TCP/IP-ports. That server shares all of those printers and pushes them using GPO/GPP to some clients. The printers are shared by the server to have only one place to configure which tray to use for which printer etc. There's additionally an app which needs to get those printers configured using a dialog showing available printers ONLY, there's no chance to simply write arbitrary printer names or alike. That dialog only shows what's known currently to the client Windows.

The problem is that this special configuration dialog can only be executed by some users who DO NOT get the shared printers. OTOH, those users who get the shared printers are not allowed to change the corresponding configuration within the app. Though, on the server I have the printers AND are allowed to configure the corresponding setting in the app, BUT the server only has local printer names, NO shares in that dialog. That dialog is simply a list showing all printers on the executing system without any way to search for any other printers. So when configuring the server-local printers in that app, things still don't work for other clients because the printers simply don't exist on those with the configured name.

**Is there a way to make the server consume it's own shared printers?**

I tried simply installing such a share on the server and things don't work, error #123 is printed with code 0x0000007b, telling about invalid file names and alike. Additionally, when renaming the printer itself, but NOT the shared named, things still don't work, because the search for printers in the network only shows the printer name instead of the share name. So those don't seem to be different in the end at all, even configured differently. I hoped to have something like "printer1_local" on the server being shared as "printer1" and only that name consumed by clients and the server alike.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you not change the printer name within "Printer Properties" on the device the printer is physically connected to? I can't read your last screenshot since it's not in English.  What is it supposed to represent? Perhaps I have missed understood your question your question.

Comment: The app always needs the same exact printer names wherever it is executed. Though, shared printers consumed by clients are named differently by Windows than the same printers available on the server. For the server these are simply local printers, not consumed shares. If the server would be able to consume it's own share instead, clients+servers would have the same printer names for consumed printers. Though, that doesn't seem to work at all for the server, it seems unable to consume its own shares and doesn't provide the chance to e.g. rename things or alike. All attempts simply fail.